# Why does LIKE not work with CONCAT but works with STRING value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Please look on the following scenario;

```
my_db=# select version();
                                                              version
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.9 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Debian 9.6.9-2.pgdg90+1), compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit


CREATE TABLE binary_data ("data" BYTEA NOT NULL);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_string(lengh integer) 
RETURNS varchar AS $$ 
  SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(
          SELECT substr('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv',trunc(random()*21+1)::int,1)       
             FROM generate_series(1,$1)),'')
$$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
insert into binary_data ("data") select CONVERT_TO(random_string(64), 'utf8') FROM generate_series(1,1000000);
```

Now if we run following query it works really well;

```
select CONVERT_FROM(data, 'utf8') from binary_data where "data" like '%me%' limit 10;
```

Bu if we run following query;

```
select CONVERT_FROM(data, 'utf8') from binary_data where "data" like CONCAT('%', 'me', '%') limit 10;
```

It failed with following error

```
Kernel error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: bytea ~~ text
```

Can't understand what's the difference between `'%me%'` and `CONCAT('%', 'me', '%')`.

First guess was the type must be different to check it I run:

```
SELECT pg_typeof('%me'), pg_typeof(CONCAT('%', 'me', '%'));
```

And yes my guess was right;

```
unknown text
```

So '%me%' is treated as `unknown` and `CONCAT('%', 'me', '%')` is treated as `text`. To use the same query with `CONCAT('%', 'me', '%')::UNKNOWN` result to another error.

```
Kernel error: ERROR:  failed to find conversion function from unknown to bytea
```

Any one have any idea what's going wrong with above queries?

Comment: Have you tried to change `RETURNS varchar AS $$` by `RETURNS text AS $$`? It seems just a CAST issue.

Comment: Please always start by declaring the version of Postgres you use. `SELECT version();` helps

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Just updated and added the version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can't understand what's the difference between `'%me%'` and `CONCAT('%', 'me', '%')`.

The first is an [**untyped string literal**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS). The second is type **`text`** since the function `concat()` returns `text`. Not exactly the same thing for [**Operator Type Resolution**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/typeconv-oper.html)! Quoting the manual there:

> 3. Look for the best match.
>
>    a. Discard candidate operators for which the input types do not match
>      and cannot be converted (using an implicit conversion) to match.
>      `unknown` literals are assumed to be convertible to anything for this
>      purpose. If only one candidate remains, use it; else continue to the
>      next step.

And there is no *implicit* conversion for `text` -> `bytea` in standard Postgres.
And there is no variant of `LIKE` for `bytea` / `text`, only for:

`bytea` / `bytea`
`name` / `text`
`text` / `text`

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=cb50f519d4409b7ab185e94f7bb22ab3)* ([testing in Postgres 11](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dbf82532ea7bb0460536e418647f08b0))

To solve, add an *explicit* cast to `bytea` (`text` can be cast to *any* type):

```
SELECT CONVERT_FROM(data, 'utf8')
FROM   binary_data
WHERE  "data" LIKE ('%' || 'me' || '%')::bytea  --!
LIMIT  10;
```